# change background image in no time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing background image of a div on event basis,

There are two image

Image1
and 
Image2

I have to use these two images on condition basis, it is working fine, but at first time when i change image, it takes time to load, how to load it instantly

div has image1 as default background image,
and I am changing it with below code

```
$("div").addClass('loadalternateImage');
```

alternate image is class with background-image with image2

but it take time to load Image2.

Please advise how to load it instantly

Thanks

Comment: Generally it happens , Make it as sprite image just change a background position

Answer (score 3):

You can preload both images in a div outside the viewport. So, when you click in order to change background, both images should have been loaded.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="first/img" />
    <img src="second/img" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100000px;
}
```

You can also bind the click event after page loads (not on document ready) in order for the images to get fully loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '#your-div', function() {
         // change background
     });
});
```

Comment: Yup beat me into it while typing.  Lol

Comment: I have to use it as background-image

Comment: You can use them as css background-image. The images should have been loaded

Comment: I have tried with a fake div and set it to background image with imag2 and set it as display none, but it has no effect at all

Comment: using ` top: -100000px;` seems a bad idea. Use `display: none` instead.

Comment: Do not set as display:none, just move the container outside the viewport. You can also set visibility: hidden, but the space would be ocupied.

Comment: but then that will be visible

Comment: If you set a position:fixed or relative, and a top: -10000px, the div will move 10000px over the screen and it would not be visible! But do not set display:none because the images will not get loaded until the div gets a property o display:block (or anything else of none)

Comment: @kapantzak This is not true. Image still is loaded with the `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

I suggest you to have a look at [this post](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Therefore, you could use the `base64` encoding for your image and put it directly to your stylesheet:

```
loadalternateImage { 
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,....) no-repeat left center;
}
```

#### Option 2

Alternatively, you could put this your into some invisible node, which would also trigger the preloading:

```
<img src="original.jpg">
<img src="secondary.jpg" style="display:none;">
```

#### Option 3

Use sprites - have a look at [this post](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). It is the most difficult solution from the maintenance point of view

Answer (score 0):

Ok retain the  answer by @kapantzak but do this

Switch between

```
$("#imgBackground')[0].src = $("#firstImg")[0].src

and

$("#imgBackground')[0].src = $("#secondImg")[0].src
```

## imgBackground is the id of IMG tag as your background.

```
 //Code block from @kapantzak
 $(window).load(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '#your-div', function() {
        // put the code above here..
     });
  });
```